# About macOS: why my user not in sudoers file but I can use sudo privileges too?

Tags: osx, sudo, passwd

In Linux, if the user that you created want to use sudo privileges, you should add this user to `/etc/sudoers`(add something like `jack ALL = (ALL) ALL`). Well, the default mac user(the one you login to mac when you turn on you Mac) can use sudo too, but it's not in `/etc/sudoers` file, but root user is in it, do you guys know how mac perform this?

As far as I know, the user I mentioned above is not in `/etc/passwd` too, I found it in `/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/XXX.plist`, xxx is your user name.

Answer (score 2):

By default, your initial user (and other users listed as "Admins") will be in the `admin` group, and there's a line in `/etc/sudoers` on macOS reading

```
%admin          ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

which gives members of the `admin` group rights to use `sudo`.

macOS uses its "Open Directory" service for storing the login details of new users, not the `/etc/passwd` file.  See `man opendirectoryd` on your macOS system for more information about that.

Comment: Thank you so much, I found the group file `admin.plist` in `/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/groups`，and my initial user is exactly right here, haha:

https://imgur.com/a/Io903mz